# How do you suffix the end of a bash file?

Tags: bash

I know this is probably me being dumb, but here's what I'm confused on:

1. What are the suffixes called at the end of a file?
   ie. .txt, .php, .html, etc
2. What suffix does a bash file use? .bash?

Thanks for helping my stupidity to be no more.

Comment: prefix->before , suffix->After

Comment: 'Prefixes' come at the start; 'suffixes' are at the end, but they're usually called 'extensions'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are called *file extensions*. By convention, shell scripts including Bash scripts get a `.sh` extension (for "SHell script").

Note that this is not a requirement for the script to execute. You can leave it off, or give it a different file extension (such as `.bashrc` for example, for the default Bash initialization script) and it will still run all the same.

Comment: It's also fairly common for bash scripts to have a `.bash` extension, which I prefer to `.sh` because `sh` is the name of a specific shell. But as you say, no particular extension is necessary. In most cases, there's no reason that the person running the script should need to care whether it's a bash script, a Perl script, or an executable.

Comment: You say _by convention_, but is it _really_ a convention? Who's the authority of a convention?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: By definition, a convention has no authority. It's just what most people do. Of course there are those who will be "unconventional" for any number of reasons. It doesn't change the fact that the majority do things one way.

Comment: Then how did you count this "most people" thing? the _real_ bash programmers don't use any extension — _by convention_

Comment: I'm a *real* programmer, @gniourf_gniourf, just as Keith is, and yet use `.bash`. This is a silly discussion.

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart good for you! keep on spreading bad and useless practices!

Comment: Passive aggression won't get you anywhere, @gniourf_gniourf.

Answer (score 4):

There's what some (a lot!) people do, for no reason I can understand: they give the `.sh` extension to *bash* scripts. It's confusing: `.sh` should be for `sh` scripts.

In fact, do we really care to have an extension for an executable? do the end users really care that the script is in Bash, Perl or Python? do the binary executables have the `.elf` extension?

Let me quote the excellent [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts) by Lhunath and GreyCat about this:

> Also, please refrain from giving your scripts that stupid .sh extension. It serves no purpose, and it's completely misleading (since it's going to be a bash script, not an sh script).

Just for fun, you can try to find some scripts in Bash on your system:

```
file /bin/* | grep Bourne
```

On my system I have these:

```
/bin/gunzip:                  Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/gzexe:                   Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/init-checkconf:          Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/uncompress:              Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/zcat:                    Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/zcmp:                    Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/zdiff:                   Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/zegrep:                  Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/zfgrep:                  Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/zforce:                  Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/zgrep:                   Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/zless:                   Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/zmore:                   Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/bin/znew:                    Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

and as you can see, they have no extensions at all!

Comment: Worth pointing out that, in `/bin/`, programs are expected not to have any extensions because they should be invoked as commands. So, in `/bin/`, this is an example of a place where `.sh` is normally not seen.

Comment: @nneonneo Well, on my system, some python scripts in `/usr/bin` have the `.py` extension, but _none of the bash scripts have extensions_. Weird eh?

Answer (score 3):

On unixoid systems (so for example GNU/Linux) such "file extensions" (or name suffixes) are much less important than on other systems. This is because the type of a file is determined on a more robust strategy and also depends on the files actual content which clearly makes sense...

By convention shell scripts often either get a ".sh" extension or none at all.

In most cases no extension makes much more sense because it is more convenient: if a script has a "shebang" in its first line(`#!/bin/bash`). In such case you can call such a script just by its name (file path) without having to specify the interpreter to open it (the shell). All that is required then is to grant the execution permission ("x-bit") to the file which is stored inside the file system on unixoid systems. So such a file can be executed by a simple and convenient `> /path/to/script` or even just by its name (`> script`) when it is located in a folder listen in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The first part is partially true. Actually, a number of utilities (such as ImageMagick) actually do care about the file extension, and will behave differently depending on the file extension supplied. The extensions may just be convention, but people by-and-large still use them extensively.

Comment: @nneonneo I did not (want to) claim that the file name extension is not considered at all in that algorithm. I added an "also" to make this more clear, so thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, the suffix can be whatever you want them to be.

Unlike Windows, the suffix of the file doesn't determine the program that runs it. Instead, Unix uses a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). The first line of a script will have a `#!` followed by the name of the processor to use:

```
#! /usr/bash    # Will execute with the default BASH shell
```

Sometimes, you will see this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env foo
```

This is a special trick where if `foo` is in your path, the `/usr/bin/env foo` will use the version of `foo` in your path. For example, I have a half dozen Perls installed, and I choose which to install via my `$PATH`. I put this in all of my Perl scripts:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
```

And, it will execute with the correct version of Perl.

---

### And now for a completely contradictory statement...

On the Unix command line, using the standard Unix shells, the *shebang* as mentioned above is used. This may or may not be the case of the graphical managers found on many Unix systems. For example, Mac OS X (Yes, that's Unix) Finder does use the suffix to determine the default program used to open the file (although this can be overwritten on a per file basis).

On Linux, Gnome Files (formally Nautilus) also uses file suffixes. I don't know what Konqueror (the KDE file browser) does. However, these can be modified for you any way you'd like. Again, there's no official list.

That said, most people use `.sh` for any shell script -- especially those Bourne-style shell scripting languages like BASH, Kornshell, Zsh, Ash, Dash, and of course, Bourne shell. Sometimes people will use `.bash`, `.ksh`, or `.zsh`, but that's rare.

Comment: This is not really true the way you put it: a shebang _may_ be used, but there certainly are other options.

Comment: Without a shebang, the script will attempt to run with the _default shell_ — which may or may not do what you want. As I stated, graphical browsers do associate file extensions with files, but this association is not fixed. What we think of as _defaults_ is not much more than claim staking. A program _claims_ a suffix, and others may ignore that claim. I figured if there was an official list, it would be MIME Types. However, there is no offical list for MIME Type suffix mapping.

Comment: Sorry, but it is possible and often makes sense to run a script by calling a shell in a specific way: `bash test`